# Group by two columns and calculate cumulative value based on one of them

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, group-by

Please consider this list:

```cs
List<Data> lst = new List<Data>
{
    new Data() { Id = 1, Val1 = 100 },
    new Data() { Id = 1, Val1 = 200 },
    new Data() { Id = 1, Val1 = 300 },
    new Data() { Id = 2, Val1 = 100 },
    new Data() { Id = 2, Val1 = 200 },
    new Data() { Id = 3, Val1 = 300 },
    new Data() { Id = 3, Val1 = 300 },
    new Data() { Id = 3, Val1 = 300 },
    new Data() { Id = 1, Val1 = 200 },
    new Data() { Id = 1, Val1 = 200 },
    new Data() { Id = 1, Val1 = 200 },
    new Data() { Id = 2, Val1 = 200 },
    new Data() { Id = 3, Val1 = 100 },
    new Data() { Id = 3, Val1 = 100 },
};
```

and then this code:

```cs
decimal Cumulative_Probability = 0;
var Result1 = (lst.OrderBy(o => o.Id).GroupBy(x => new { x.Val1 })
    .Select(y => new
    {
        y.Key.Val1,
        Probability = (Convert.ToDecimal(y.Count()) / lst.Count),
        Cumulative_Probability = (Cumulative_Probability = 
            Cumulative_Probability + 
            (Convert.ToDecimal(y.Count()) / lst.Count))
    })).OrderBy(o => o.Val1).ToList();
```

this code works fine and `Cumulative_Probability` calculated correctly.

Now please consider this code:

```cs
decimal Cumulative_Probability2 = 0;
var Result2 = (lst.OrderBy(o => o.Id).GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Val1 })
    .Select(y => new
    {
        y.Key.Id,
        y.Key.Val1,
        Probability = (Convert.ToDecimal(y.Count()) 
            / lst.Where(o => o.Id == y.Key.Id).Count()),
        Cumulative_Probability = (Cumulative_Probability2 = 
            Cumulative_Probability2 + 
            (Convert.ToDecimal(y.Count()) / 
            lst.Where(o => o.Id == y.Key.Id).Count()))
    })).OrderBy(o => o.Id).ThenBy(o => o.Val1).ToList();
```

this code generate this result:

[image]

As you can see `Probability` calculated in each group correctly, but not `Cumulative_Probability`. I want to calculate `Cumulative_Probability` in each **Id** group (group records first accourding `Id` then `Val1`) and `Cumulative_Probability2` doesn't reset in each group. How I can calculate `Cumulative_Probability` in each group?

Thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I want this result:

```
 Id             Val1             Probability       Cumulative_Probability 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              100                0.16                 0.16
 1              200                0.66                 0.82
 1              300                0.16                 0.98
 2              100                0.33                 0.33
 2              200                0.66                 0.66
 ...
```

Comment: Can you show what your expected output is?

Comment: I get it now, you want the cumulative for that Id only

Comment: You wand the sum of previous values for each ID.  So you want Probability.Select((x, i) => x.Take(i + 1).Sum())

Comment: @jdweng You consider that `Id`s are `1,2,3,...` but in real world I have `Id`s like `1401, 2012, 3232, ...`

Comment: A GroupBy creates a 2 dimensional array <key,List<object>> : Probability.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.Select((y,i) => new {id = x.Key, p = y, c= x.Take(i + 1).Sum()})).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng please write your solutio as answer so me and other users better understand it. Th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
var Result2 = (from a in lst.OrderBy(o => o.Id)
               group a by new { a.Id, a.Val1 } into grp
               select new
               {
                   grp.Key.Id,
                   grp.Key.Val1,
                   Probability = (Convert.ToDecimal(grp.Count()) / lst.Where(o => o.Id == grp.Key.Id).Count()),
                   Cumulative_Probability = (from b in lst.Where(o => o.Id == grp.Key.Id && o.Val1 <= grp.Key.Val1)
                                             group b by new { b.Val1 } into grp2
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 Probability2 = (Convert.ToDecimal(grp2.Count()) / lst.Where(o => o.Id == grp.Key.Id).Count())
                                             }).Sum(o => o.Probability2)
                }).OrderBy(o => o.Id).ThenBy(o => o.Val1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with the help of an extension method which accumulates the cumulative probability, along with some nested `GroupBy`. I'm sure there must be an easier way, but I'm scratching my head trying to find it.

The extension is:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Accumulate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        TAccumulate seed, 
        Func<TAccumulate, TSource, (TAccumulate,TResult)> accumulator)
    {
        var acc = seed;
        foreach(TSource value in source)
        {
            var (newSeed, newSource) = accumulator.Invoke(acc, value);
            yield return newSource;
            acc = newSeed;
        }
    }
}
```

And the finished code looks like:

```
var result = lst.GroupBy( x => x.Id)
        .SelectMany( (grpId,i) =>  grpId.GroupBy(x => x.Val1)
                    .Accumulate(0M, (acc,grpVal) => (acc + (decimal)grpVal.Count()/grpId.Count(), new {
                        Id = grpId.Key,
                        Val1 = grpVal.Key,
                        Probability = (decimal)grpVal.Count()/grpId.Count(),
                        Cumulative_Probability = acc + ((decimal)grpVal.Count()/grpId.Count())
                    }))
                   )
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dvW1qo

Comment: Great! I saw this question a little bit to late! I like tasks like this one :-)

Comment: @DavidStania me too. I hate my answer though for repeating the calculation of probability 3 times.

Comment: Thanks dear friend for your solution. I think there must be an easier way too. We must hope that @JonSkeet sees this question :D.

Comment: @Jamiec I add an answer and it works. Thanks for your help